# Firebase 9 custom thumbnail path doc upload and thumbnail load for avatar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Im trying to rewrite 4 lines of firebase v8 code to work with v9.... but I'm stuck on these 3 lines, even after studying Firebase documentation.... This code is found within a form submit function and taken from one of Shaun Pelling's (the Net Ninja's) Udemy Firebase/React Course.

The code serves a pretty simple purpose:

I'd like to upload the comment to a custom file path within firebase taking in the userId (uid) previously defined as a variable in the filepath. Then upload the file. In my nabber I also have an image being displayed from the url created by the 3rd line of code.

**EDIT:** First, here's the JSX to which the file originally is uploaded from:

```
<label>
  <span>Upload Profile Thumbnail:</span>
  <input
   required
   type="file"
   id="thumbnail"
   name="thumbnail"
  />
</label>
```

the original 4 lines I'm referring to (v8):

```
  const res = await projectAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        
  const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`
  const image = await projectStorage.ref(uploadPath).put(thumbnail)
  const imageUrl = await image.ref.getDownloadURL()

  await res.user.updateProfile({ photoURL: imageUrl })
```

This is kind of what I've got. (It's a mess I don't don't think it even makes much sense. I'm a bit lost, so if it confuses you as well, please disregard... I just wanted to show I'm trying \(˚☐˚”)/)

```
  import { ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from 'firebase/storage'
  import { updateProfile } from 'firebase/auth'
  
  const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`
  const imageUrl = getDownloadURL(ref(storage, image))
  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata )

  updateProfile(user, { photoURL: imageUrl})
```

**SIDENOTE:**
Oh, 1 little probably much less important sidenote (and more than likely unnecessary), In the v8 example, the thumbnail is uploaded within the signup form, hence the signup function in the first bit of code. In the second example v9, I created a whole new page (only available to signed in users) so that they can upload a thumbnail at a later time. In order to do so, I'm picking up the "user" object from the currentlysignedin user to be able to for instance use the updateProfile function. ie:

```
  // within the v9 code example
  const { user } = useAuthContext()


  //=======================================
  // in the useAuthContext File:

  import { AuthContext } from "../CONTEXT/AuthContext.js"
  import { useContext } from "react"

  export const useAuthContext = () => {
   const context = useContext(AuthContext)
   return context
  }


  //=======================================
  // in the authContext File:

  import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react'
  import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
  import { auth } from '../Firebase/config'

  export const AuthContext = createContext()

  export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
   case 'LOGIN':
    return { ...state, user: action.payload }
   case 'LOGOUT':
    return { ...state, user: null }
   case 'AUTH_IS_READY':
    return { user: action.payload, authIsReady: true }
   default:
  return state
 }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, { 
  user: null,
  authIsReady: false
})

useEffect(() => {
 const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_IS_READY', payload: user })
  unsub()
 })
}, [])

// console.log('AuthContext state:', state)

return (
 <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
  { children }
 </AuthContext.Provider>
)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the V9 code snippet, you are trying to get the download URL before even uploading the image at first place. Also if you don't need to track update progress, use `uploadBytes()` instead:

```
import { ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from 'firebase/storage'
import { updateProfile } from 'firebase/auth'

// pass the path in ref to create a StorageReference
const storageRef = ref(storage, `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`)

// upload image, file is a blob here
await uploadBytes(storageRef, file);

const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);

// this function returns promise too, add await 
await updateProfile(user, { photoURL: downloadUrl })
```

Comment: Just have a few issues: Since in the v9 version, I'm not signingupwithemailandpassword, I dnot believe I get a response back (res) and since I've already gotten the user variable defined I switched the storage ref line from "ref.user.id" to "user.id".I think it should work.The blob "file" is coming back as undefined. I saw this in the documentation too. idk if I'm supposed to leave it as is, or reference it as a variable like: const file = document.querySelector('#...')? I'm unfamiliar with he term or its use. I read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Blob

Comment: @MichaelMartell can you update your question so we can see where the file is coming from ?

Comment: yeah, no problem, Done.

Comment: @MichaelMartell I see the input field but not where the variable `file` in code is declared and how is it getting the value from the input field.

Comment: ohhhh! I think that's what I was missing. in the v8 code, it had onChange={handleChange}setThumbnail(null)
    let selectedFile = e.target.files[0]
    setThumbnail(selectedFile)... I'll edit it now. I think I'm finally understanding why v8 works...

Comment: @MichaelMartell yes, the Firebase related code in my answer should work as intended if you are providing the relevant data correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245220/discussion-between-michael-martell-and-dharmaraj).